# Initialize a children button when using a cascade dropdown menu via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have set up a dropdown menu cascade (children: location and parent: country) and I would like the children and parent to be initialized at the first default value coming when landing in the page. For the parent dropdown menu it's pretty straight forward but for the children the way the cascade is designed does not allow to make appear the first default value or even the options unless the country button changes. I will share with you the code so that it is more understandable

HTML :
parent

```
<select type="button" id="country" name="country" placeholder="Phantasyland">
  <option value="Market" selected="selected">
    MARKETPLACE - Disruptive Growth
  </option>
  <option value="Workplace">WORKPLACE - Foundations</option>
  <option value="PC">PEOPLE & CULTURE - Business Leadership</option>
</select>
```

[...]
children

```
<div class="tooltips" title="Please select the city that the customer is primarily to be served from.">
    <select id="location" name="location" placeholder="Anycity"></select>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var locations = {
    Market: [
      "1. Activate Priority Destinations",
      "2. Drive Growth through Trade Partnerships",
      "3. Lead the travel ecosystem to own Arabia",
      "4. Create a welcoming and frictionless experience",
    ],
    Workplace: [
      "5. Empower STA with evidence-based decision making",
      "6. Organize High-Performance organization for STA",
    ],
    PC: [
      "7. Enable STArs success, growth and wellbeing",
      "8. Foster & embrace our core values",
    ],
  };

  var $locations = $("#location");
  $("#country").change(function () {
    var country = $(this).val(),
      lcns = locations[country] || [];

    var html = $.map(lcns, function (lcn) {
      return '<option value="' + lcn + '">' + lcn + "</option>";
    }).join("");

    $locations.html(html);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".group").hide();
  $("#Market").show();
  $("#country").change(function () {
    $(".group").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

Would you have an idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually just do the same thing that is done in the `onchange` of `#country` on initialisation. Refer the below code. I've just moved it to a re-usable method.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var locations = {
    Market: [
      "1. Activate Priority Destinations",
      "2. Drive Growth through Trade Partnerships",
      "3. Lead the travel ecosystem to own Arabia",
      "4. Create a welcoming and frictionless experience",
    ],
    Workplace: [
      "5. Empower STA with evidence-based decision making",
      "6. Organize High-Performance organization for STA",
    ],
    PC: [
      "7. Enable STArs success, growth and wellbeing",
      "8. Foster & embrace our core values",
    ],
  };

  function populateLocation(country) {
    var lcns = locations[country] || [];

    var html = $.map(lcns, function(lcn) {
      return '<option value="' + lcn + '">' + lcn + "</option>";
    }).join("");

    var $locations = $("#location");

    $locations.html(html);
  };
  
  populateLocation($("#country").val());

  $("#country").change(function() {
    var country = $(this).val();
    populateLocation(country);
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".group").hide();
  $("#Market").show();
  $("#country").change(function() {
    $(".group").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select type="button" id="country" name="country" placeholder="Phantasyland">
  <option value="Market" selected="selected">
    MARKETPLACE - Disruptive Growth
  </option>
  <option value="Workplace">WORKPLACE - Foundations</option>
  <option value="PC">PEOPLE & CULTURE - Business Leadership</option>
</select>

<div class="tooltips" title="Please select the city that the customer is primarily to be served from.">
  <select id="location" name="location" placeholder="Anycity"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing thank for your so fast and accurate answer, I am a total beginner in jquery/html

Comment: Quick one @parkourkarthik let say I want to fill in a html page refering to one of the options taken y the children dropdown location, how would I do that to select the appropriate option value in this case ?

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, you can accept the answer. For the specific question, there are many ways to do that. It depends on the html page that you mean, is it a file or html element? You can lookup that with your specific needs I believe.

Comment: Y es I just did

Comment: Two questions :1)Let's say I want to create a div content that will display something depending on what has been selected on the children button, I guess it would be something llike $("#locations".val()).show(); for js and then <div id="1. Activate des[...]" but it does not work     2) I want to customize the populate function for children button : that is to say link to another main page button that will make appear the second option of the children button for this specific button. Is there any method to add another populate function that will do that ?  sorry for the tons of questions ...